# prove that the sum of the elements A is divisible by 5

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

Let A be a set of 5 integers. Denote $S= \{x+y \mid x,y \in A\}$ . Given that S has 9 elements, prove that the sum of the elements A is divisible by 5

Comment: What have you tried? Also it may help to think what the maximal number of element that $S$ can possibly have is..

Comment: my tried: i'll use Dirichlet but....

Comment: You might do well to think about the *minimum* number of elements that $S$ can have also...

Comment: Can certain integers have same value? Can repeated sum used?

Answer (score 1):

Identify the elements of $A$ in ascending order as $a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5$.

Then $S$ definitely contains (in ascending order) the nine elements $\{a_1+a_1, a_1+a_2, a_2+a_2, a_2+a_3, a_3+a_3, a_3+a_4, a_4+a_4, a_4+a_5, a_5+a_5 \}$. Therefore other possible sums from $A$ must equal one of these; in fact we must have:

$\begin{align}
a_3+a_5 &= a_4+ a_4 \\
a_2+a_4 &= a_3+a_3  \\
a_2+a_5 &= a_3+ a_4 \\
a_1+a_3 &= a_2+ a_2 \\
a_1+a_4 &= a_2+ a_3, \text{ and }\\
a_1+a_5 &= a_2+ a_4 = a_3+a_3\\
\end{align}$

Then $\sum a_i = (a_1+a_5) + (a_2+ a_4) + a_3  = 5a_3$, divisible by $5$ as required.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are no repeated (in the creating of A and S) the total sums possible for S are 10 values and the Sum of these values is 4 times the sum of the integers in A.
Let A = {1,2,3,4,5}. The sum of the 10 values is 60. Avoid using any sum of A integers that is different than 6 and the above is not true.